# Extracting columns from a file (more than 22354 columns)

Tags: awk, sed, cut, gawk

I should extract around 50k columns from a file that have 150k columns. I tried `cut`. But `cut` only support 22354 columns.

The column numbers are in a file and I should extract that columns from the main file.

The file look like this:

```
    .001 .2 0 0 1 2.3456
    1 2 4.567 2.12 0 7
    1 2 1 2 0 1
```

The cut work but only for the first 22354.

`cut -d" " -f2,4` # I have 50k numbers to put after `f`.

It is possible to cut the file three times and paste them together! I look for a better way.

Comment: Any sample data format?

Comment: What does the file content mean?

Comment: `awk` and `perl` seem to be able to handle such large number of columns with ease. Have you tried anything with `awk` yet?

Answer (score 1):

```
awk -v "LastCol=50000" '{
   if (NF > LastCol){
      for( i = 1; i < LastCol; i++) printf "%s%s", $i, FS
      print $LastCol
      }
    else print
   }' File > File.crop
```

Tested with 150K column `(seq -s " " 150000)` and works here

Answer (score 1):

To bypass any command-line length limits (as well as any cut limits), you may want to do this with `awk -f` instead. Put your column list in a file:

```
columnfile:
{print [comma-separated list of your column numbers each preceded by "$"]}
```

Then just:

```
awk -f columnfile < [your input file]
```

Comment: ??? problem is on a `cut` limitation, not a awk and writing a command line that have 50K column preceded by `$` is not frequent in code.

Comment: For the first time awk has run out of memory!

Comment: On my system `awk` is really `mawk 1.3` and I get: `awk: program limit exceeded: maximum number of fields size=32767`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sed`, I'm not sure what its limits are but `sed` can handle 150000 columns easy and it's quick. In the first pass, switch all the field delimiters to newlines for `sed`, then use the `-n` option to suppress output and specify the column ranges with the `sed` print command `p`.

E.g. 
`seq -s " " 150000 > myfile.txt`

`sed -r 's/[ ]+/ /g;s/ /\n/g' myfile.txt | sed -n '55455,60000p;115000,125000p'`

`Note:` Don't forget to do your column math, since now the columns are rows, you need to multiply the former row numbers by the number of columns.